# How can I disable OpenGL in the Haskell Platform?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-platform

I'm on a shared Linux server where I can't install software. It seems like installing OpenGL from source is a major pain (I stopped after finding that Mesa depends on libxml2), and I don't use it in any of my Haskell programs.

**How do I disable OpenGL in the Haskell platform?** I got around the configure checks by deleting those, but when I add `--disable-OpenGLRaw` or `--without-OpenGLRaw` to the `./configure` options, it says "unrecognized options" and doesn't actually disable the packages.

Also, I've tried using the cabal-install bootstrap, but for some reason `cabal-install 0.14.0` doesn't work with GHC 7.6.3.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Is there a reason not to use cabal-install 1.16.X?  The 'Cabal' webpage always lags - it seems no one considers it their job to update that page.  See the hackage page instead.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson ooh, I don't know about the version inflation, but that seems to work! Please add this as an answer (URL is http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-install --> download package link, it includes the same `bootstrap.sh` as instructions list), and I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use cabal-install 1.16.X with GHC 7.6.3. The 'Cabal' webpage always lags - it seems no one considers it their job to update that page. See the hackage page instead (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-install).

Answer (score 5):

After a bit of mucking, I seem to have gotten it. Send me an email if I'm missing an instruction,

- Comment out lines printing errors from `./configure` (or replace them with `echo` to keep syntax parity)
- Delete all GL things (fgl, OpenGLRaw, GLUT, etc.) from `packages/haskell-platform-*/haskell-platform.cabal` and `packages/platform.packages`

The lines you're supposed to delete look like this,

```
as_fn_error $? "The OpenGL C library is required" "$LINENO" 5
```

If you're stuck, here's a really bad diff that somehow works (http://pastebin.com/azWNHsh8). Don't ask me, I deleted an `if` by mistake and deleted a `fi` elsewhere and it works ......

Hopefully the `--disable-X` flags will work in a future version of the platform.